# Order SQL request when each row contains id of the next one

Tags: sql, postgresql, request

I have 2 tables in my database: `BusLines` & `BusStops`. Each instance of `BusLines` can have many stops associated with it, in a particular order. To make the associations easier to manage (delete or add new stops in an existing line), the associative table has been designed with the following structure:

`id_BusLine | id_BusStop | id_NextBusStop | isFirstStop`

It seemed like a good idea to do it this way instead of giving each stop a number, which would have to be changed for every record once new stops have to be added to the beginning of the line (but if you have a better idea, I would sure like to hear it).

So, to reiterate: how could I create a SELECT statement on each line to have all the stops in the right order? Because I can't solve it with just a simple ORDER BY...

Comment: Which SQL dialect?   Microsoft SQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc.

Comment: oups sorry: PostgreSQL

Comment: Your PostgreSQL version? Your table definition with data types? Some sample data? Are there circular references if a busline makes a round trip? How do you deal with those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solutions for SQL Server 2008-2012, PostgreSQL 9.1.9, Oracle 11g**

Actually, recursive CTE is a solution for almost all current RDBMS, including PostgreSQL (explanations and example shown below). However there is another better solution (optimized) for Oracle DBs: hierarchical queries.

NOCYCLE instructs Oracle to return rows even if  your data has a loop in it.

CONNECT_BY_ROOT gives you access to the root element, even several layers down in the query.

Using the HR schema:

**The corresponding code for Oracle 11g:**

```
select
b.id_bus_line, b.id_bus_stop
from BusLine_BusStop b
start with b.is_first_stop = 1
connect by nocycle prior b.id_next_bus_stop = b.id_bus_stop and prior b.id_bus_line = b.id_bus_line
```

[DEMO for Oracle 11g](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/535ae/26) (code of my own).

Please note that the standard is recursive CTE in the SQL:1999 norm. As you can see, there are several differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

**The following solution is for SQL Server 2012:**

```
;WITH route AS
(
  SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId, NextBusStopId
  FROM BusLine_BusStop
  WHERE IsFirstStop = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.BusLineId, b.BusStopId, b.NextBusStopId
  FROM BusLine_BusStop b
  INNER JOIN route r
          ON r.BusLineId = b.BusLineId
         AND r.NextBusStopId = b.BusStopId
  WHERE IsFirstStop = 0 or IsFirstStop is null
)
SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId
FROM route
ORDER BY BusLineId
```

[DEMO for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83734/2) (inspired by T I).

**And this one is for PostgreSQL 9.1.9 (it is not optimal but should work):**

The trick consists in the creation of a dedicated temporary sequence for the current session that you can reset.

```
create temp sequence rownum;

WITH final_route AS
(
  WITH RECURSIVE route AS
  (
    SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId, NextBusStopId
    FROM BusLine_BusStop
    WHERE IsFirstStop = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.BusLineId, b.BusStopId, b.NextBusStopId
    FROM BusLine_BusStop b
    INNER JOIN route r
            ON r.BusLineId = b.BusLineId
           AND r.NextBusStopId = b.BusStopId
    WHERE IsFirstStop = 0 or IsFirstStop is null
  )
  SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId, nextval('rownum') as rownum
  FROM route
)
SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId
FROM final_route
ORDER BY BusLineId, rownum;
```

[DEMO for PostgreSQL 9.1.9](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/15d28/18) of my own.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the multiple edits. It is quite uncommon to connect records by children record instead of by its parent.
You can avoid this poor representation by dropping your isFirstStop column and connecting your records using an id_PreviousBusStop column (if possible). In that case, you have to set id_PreviousBusStop to null for the first record.
You may save space (for fixed-length data, the entire space is still reserved). Moreover your queries will then become more efficient using less characters.

Comment: yeah I thought about adding a column id_PreviousBusStop so it's not a problem at all to do that. I'm using postgre and i can't try your solution now but sure I'll try!

Comment: you are welcome. For the other, feel free to edit the code above if you would like to improve it. The code actually works OK at sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: I just noticed you gave details about your SGBD. Postgre uses recursive CTE so the second solution would be adequate.

Comment: I've just tried your solution (with changing the column isFirstStop by PreviousBusStopId) and it works PERFECTLY! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If using sql server then I think a recursive cte like this works

```
;WITH route AS
(
  SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId, NextBusStopId
  FROM BusLine_BusStop
  WHERE IsFirstStop = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.BusLineId, b.BusStopId, b.NextBusStopId
  FROM BusLine_BusStop b
  INNER JOIN route r
          ON r.BusLineId = b.BusLineId
         AND r.NextBusStopId = b.BusStopId
  WHERE IsFirstStop = 0
)

SELECT BusLineId, BusStopId
FROM route
ORDER BY BusLineId
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83734/6)

Comment: The leading semicolon is an SQL Server artefact and not needed in standard SQL or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a self-join situation, something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a
JOIN table b
   ON  a.id_BusLine = b.id_Busline
   AND a.id_NextBusStop = b.id_BusStop
```

That links them together, but you'd want ordering too, if your isFirstStop is 1/0 then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a
JOIN table b
   ON  a.id_BusLine = b.id_Busline
   AND a.id_NextBusStop = b.id_BusStop
ORDER BY isFirstStop, ....
```

Need some way to order the stops after that.

Comment: I think you're on the right way and I hadn't thought about self-join request. but in fact the problem is the order, because the order is defined by the rows themselves: the first stop (isFirstStop = 1) tells which stop is the second one (id_NextBusStop) etc...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the fine SQL methods would be to copy the old BASIC trick of specifying line numbers in units of 10, so that you can still insert new ones between existing ones -- if you need to stick to integers that is.

Of course you could number in increments of 1,000 if you wanted. If you like things to be neat and tidy you could periodically run a renumbering routine to even the numbers out.

Low-tech, will work on any database at all, and the simple order-by will outperform all of the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

#### Current design

Assuming this table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE bus_lnk(
  id_busline     integer
 ,id_busstop     integer
 ,id_nextbusstop integer
 ,isfirststop    boolean
);
```

This query includes a running number for every stop per line and should be simpler and faster than what was posted so far:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
   SELECT id_busline, id_busstop, id_nextbusstop, 1 AS stop_nr
   FROM   bus_lnk
   WHERE  isfirststop               -- properly testing boolean column in pg

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT id_busline, b.id_busstop, b.id_nextbusstop, r.stop_nr + 1
   FROM   bus_lnk b
   JOIN   r USING (id_busline)      -- simple join
   WHERE  r.id_nextbusstop = b.id_busstop
   AND    isfirststop IS NOT TRUE   -- simple, proper test
   )
SELECT id_busline, id_busstop, stop_nr
FROM   r
ORDER  BY id_busline, stop_nr;
```

(SQLfiddle is down ATM.)

#### Simpler design

Since bus lines don't change on a daily basis I would suggest a simpler table layout:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE bus_lnk(
  id_busline     integer
 ,id_busstop     integer
 ,stop_rnk       integer 
);
```

You can start your numbers in `stop_rnk` with steps of 1000 (or whatever). In the event of a change, there is plenty of room in the number space to fit in more stops. To get a clean numbering without gaps, you run the comparatively simple query:

```
SELECT id_busline, id_busstop
      ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_busline ORDER BY stop_rnk) AS stop_nr
FROM   bus_lnk
ORDER  BY id_busline, stop_rnk;
```