# Loop through a table to fill an other one

Tags: postgresql, loops, request

I asked a question here fiew days ago: [Order SQL request when each row contains id of the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874590/order-sql-request-when-each-row-contains-id-of-the-next-one)

But now I'm confronted to another problem. I would like to get all bus stops per ligne in the right order, like this:

```
  id_BusLine  | id_BusStop | id_BusStop | id_BusStop | id_BusStop | id_BusStop |
--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
      1       |      4     |      8     |      2     |      1     |      6     |
      2       |      6     |      1     |      2     |      8     |      4     |
      3       |      12    |      1     |      8     |      6     |      7     |
```

In fact, my schema is a bit more complicated than the one explained in the first question, because between BusLine & BusStop, I have BusRoad, which has geographical data (doesn't matter here),id_StartBusStop and id_EndBusStop… I've made a lot of tries, but I can't find a way to loop trough the BusRoads and then apply them to BusLines…

Have you got any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are looking for is a pivot query. But that really ain't something you should do in the db, if you need to display the data like that do it in your app.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought... it's a little bit tricky and not very beautiful, but works well. for those who have the same problem: just save the value of the last id, and check for each row if he has the same id. if not, create a new instance (and save the id), if yes, just add the next bus stop.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql has a nice extension called crosstab that was made to help with this exact type of problem.

You'll need the tablefunc extension or contrib module (based on which postgres version you're on).  Here's the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html

The documentation is pretty clear, but post back if you need further help on this.